# How to convert number to its corresponding alphabet

Tags: python

For example, `1` should give me alphabet `a`,

```
2 > b
3 > c
... 
26 > a
And 27 should give an again
28 > b
.. Till 9999
```

The below code only works with 26 numbers

```
import string
di=dict(zip(string.letters,[ord(c)%32 for c in string.letters]))
di['c']
```

Output is `3`.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why do you use modulo 32 if you only have 26 symbols?

Comment: You say you want numbers to letters but created a mapping from letters to numbers... Which one is it?

Comment: @tripleee Maybe it's a leftover from a Cyrillic alphabet, which has 33 letters in it

Answer (score 2):

this would do

```py
def num2char(num):
    return chr(((num-1) % 26) + ord('a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to go through a dictionary to convert numbers to letters that way.  You can apply the modulo to positions in a string of letters

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i in range(1,1000):
  print(i,">",letters[(i-1)%26])
```

output:

```
1 > a
2 > b
3 > c
4 > d
5 > e
6 > f
7 > g
8 > h
9 > i
10 > j
11 > k
12 > l
13 > m
14 > n
15 > o
16 > p
17 > q
18 > r
19 > s
20 > t
21 > u
22 > v
23 > w
24 > x
25 > y
26 > z
27 > a
28 > b
29 > c
...
```

Comment: Better to use `string.ascii_lowercase` to avoid hard-coding the letters.

Answer (score 0):

See if either one of these is what you're looking for:

```
print (ord ('a') - 96)

print (chr (1 + 96))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is odd. If your input alphabet contains 9999 symbols, you need a dictionary of that many elements. But actually you don't really need a dictionary at all, just the observation that the input number modulo 26 plus 1 maps to the character codes starting at `a`.

```py
def strmap(numbers):
    base = ord('a')
    mapped = [chr(base + (n-1)%26) for n in numbers]
    return ''.join(mapped)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/FeVkO4

Answer (score 0):

This function transform big numbers to a string, useful for excel's columns

```py
def word(number: int) -> str:
    """Converts a number to its word equivalent
    1 -> a
    2 -> b
    ...
    25 -> y
    26 -> z
    27 -> aa
    28 -> ab
    ...
    702 -> zz
    703 -> aaa
    """
    result = ""
    number -= 1
    while True:
        resto = number % 26
        result += chr(resto + ord("a"))  # change to ord("A") to get upper case
        if number == resto:
            break
        number = (number - resto)//27
    return result[::-1]
```

to make the relation `1 -> A`, you only need to subtract one, like in commented line.